# questions about L.E. Scriven's paper

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am reading L.E. Scriven's "**On the dynamics of phase growth**", here is the link  https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0009250959800191.

My questions are about equation (36) - (42):
$$\dot{t}=K(t_{rr}+2r^{-1}t_{r})-r^{-2}R^{2}\dot{R}t_{r},\qquad\quad(36)$$
$$t(r,0)=t(\infty,\theta)=0\qquad\qquad\qquad(37)$$
$$t(R,\theta)=-\tau\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad(38)$$
$$t_{r}(R,\theta)=K^{-1}\dot{R}(\xi+\omega v\tau).\qquad\qquad(39)$$

then the author said "On dimensional grounds we assume as a solution $t(r,\theta)=t(s)$ and $$r=2\beta{\sqrt{K\theta}}\quad\quad (40)$$ where
$$s=r/2{\sqrt{K\theta}}\quad\quad (41).$$, then the equation (36) becomes
$$t_{s s}=2t_{s}(-s-s^{-1}+\epsilon\beta^{3}s^{-2})$$

I don't understand where (40) and (41) come from, why we can assume that? And how to get the last equation? Here $t$ is the temperature and $\theta$ is time variable.$R(\theta)$ is a function of time.

Comment: He is looking for **a** solution. These assumptions lead to **a** solution. That is ALL the justification that they need. That **a** solution will be **the** solution is a matter handled elsewhere (whether addressed in this paper, or as general knowledge about differential equations). He chose the form of (40) and (41) just to get the units (distance, time, etc) to come out correctly. The $2$ and $\frac 12$ were chosen to make the transformed equation as simple as possible. You get it by expressing the differentiations in (36) in terms of $t_s$ and $t_{ss}$ and simplifying.